# Where to make initialization of members of QML type?

Tags: qml

I generated a custom type polygon

```
Polygon {
             id: aPieChart
             anchors.centerIn: parent
             width: 100; height: 100
             name: "A simple polygon"
             color: "blue"
             vertices:[

             Point{x:20.0; y:40.0},
             Point{x:40.0; y:40.0},
             Point{x:20.0; y:20.0}
             ]

         }
```

Here is my polygon.h file:

```
#ifndef POLYGON_H
#define POLYGON_H


#include <QDeclarativeItem>
#include <QColor>
#include "point.h"

class Polygon : public QDeclarativeItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ name WRITE setName)
    Q_PROPERTY(QColor color READ color WRITE setColor)
    Q_PROPERTY(QDeclarativeListProperty<Point> vertices READ vertices)

public:
    Polygon(QDeclarativeItem *parent = 0);

    QString name() const;
    void setName(const QString &name);

    QColor color() const;
    void setColor(const QColor &color);

    QDeclarativeListProperty<Point> vertices();
    static void append_vertex(QDeclarativeListProperty<Point> *list, Point *vertex);

    //void Polygon::dragEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event);
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget = 0);

private:
    QString m_name;
    QColor m_color;
    QList<Point *> m_vertices;
};


#endif // POLYGON_H
```

Point is also a type generated by me.

I handle vertices with a line in polygon.h:

```
Q_PROPERTY(QDeclarativeListProperty<Point> vertices READ vertices)
```

because of the need to use points as a QVector,

i use these lines, m_vertices is the variable name that handle vertices array got from QML:

```
QVector<QPointF> vPnt;
for(int i=0;i<m_vertices.length();i++){
       vPnt.append(QPointF(m_vertices.at(i)->x(),m_vertices.at(i)->y()));

}
```

I want to ask where should i put these lines.
In paint? Then these lines run again and again where paint is called?
In constructer then, m_vertices is not initialized that time?
Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation if your Polygon inherits from QDeclarativeItem then you can also implement the [QDeclarativeParserStatus](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdeclarativeparserstatus.html) interface and you will be notified when the component is ready and values have been initialized.

That looks like a good place where to update your vPnt QVector.

(I haven't tested this solution personally)